# % share in 3 datasets or portfolios in time-series. Data or API request for my animation

Tags: data-request, api

I'm looking for an aggregate data set which shows three datasets of related data, and a percentage share for each over time.  So for example, it might show manufacturers share over time for each of 3 categories of product.  I want the shares to total 100% in each category.   Another example might be 3 portfolios of similar stocks over time.  I want this for my cross section visualization of a series of nested shells.  Each axis will be a different dataset--the equivalent of an animated pie chart.  From the middle to the outside will equal 100%.  So 5 dimensional data.

Clarification:  5 dimensions:  Time, categories (companies, for example) and 3 share dimensions, each of the 3 total 100%.  The values of category are preferably the same for the 3 share dimensions (not the share values), but not necessarily.

I'm sorry if this is vague, I don't have a particular type of data in mind.  At least 5 measurements in the time dimension would be nice.  Something cyclical in time would be nice too.  I can munge data.  Would something on data.gov work?  I'm basically a novice at data gathering, and would trade a visualization for data, Thus:

Once the 3D visualization is complete, I will post the visualization in source form here.  Here it is as it now stands: http://coderextreme.net/earth/world.html  I will animate each plane of the cross-section individually over time.

Comment: This is really, really vague.  Technically, *anything* could answer this question.  (land use, agricultural output, weather reports, employment data, etc.)

Comment: A good way to respond to this message would be market share by manufacturer for smartphone, tablets and smartwatches by quarter.

Comment: If you have the answer to the question already, why did you ask it?  It's not like this is a question with a specific enough answer that others might find useful ... it reads more like 'I have a homework assignment'.

Comment: @Joe, have you had your coffee morning?  I have a visualization, but made up data.  I would like real data.  No I am not an uber @ data-analysis or a student.  I am trying to learn how to find information.  The UCI repository is one place.   One thing I don't know how to do is find quarterly shipped goods, although I suspect that It could be found looking at companies quarterly reports.  I am not a stock/investment expert either.  I just want some data to fill into my visualization.  I realize I could so some searches myself, but I'm unfamiliar with searching for this type of data.

Comment: @Joe, so far all the "answers" I have found cost $.  I am looking for *open* data, not $50 a month.

Comment: No, because I don't drink coffee.  I'm saying you just need some metrics that's breakdowns of a whole as time series, and convert to percentages yourself -- so you could take GDP by industry, and for each time step sum them all up, then calculate each industry's % contribution.  You could look at genres on the top 40 charts.  ANYTHING can be a percentage, so long as you define what the whole is.  Take a look at the other [data request](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-request) questions, and see what sources there are, then find one w/ data that you like.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of questions I think the most useful place to search is the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/).

- [Full list of datasets](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/)

Use the filters on the left menu bar to select certain types of datasets. For example, "Time series". You'll find data sets like this:

- [Daily and Sports Activities](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Daily+and+Sports+Activities)

> The dataset comprises motion sensor data of 19 daily and sports activities each performed by 8 subjects in their own style for 5 minutes. Five Xsens MTx units are used on the torso, arms, and legs.

Comment: Looking for numerical data which I can sum to equal 100% in 3 dimensions, like 3 pie charts.  I don't see how to convert sensor data in x,y,z to %.   I would understand if it was phi and theta.

Comment: This answer fits better under my question under the metadata tag.

Comment: Apparently I can't search @ UCI by percentage, share or count for attribute type?  Am I missing something?